# Forwarding BTC without approval

Tags: output

Since all I need in order to send a transaction is the receiver address.
What is the mechanism  (if any) that stops me to send transactions to someone BTC without his approval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Since all I need in order to send a transaction is the receiver
>   address.

You also need a private key. In order to send someone coins from your wallet, you need a signed transaction with your private key.

> What is the mechanism (if any) that stops me to send transactions to
>   someone BTC without his approval?

You don't need an approval of someone to send him transaction.